# Write MS Excel Sheet

Tags: go

Can I create an MS Excel sheet using Go? Where can I find a library? Am running Go on a Mac machine for development and on a Linux machine for deployment.

Comment: You can write a CSV file using plaintext I/O.

Comment: i want it actually has an MS Excel sheet since graphs get generated from the sheet data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Microsoft Excel binary file. These are the [Microsoft Office Binary (doc, xls, ppt) File Formats](http://www.microsoft.com/interop/docs/officebinaryformats.mspx).

More recently (September 2014):

[Office Archive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj633114.aspx)

[Excel 97-2007 (XLS)](http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/0/1/501ED102-E53F-4CE0-AA6B-B0F93629DDC6/Office/Excel97-2007BinaryFileFormat(xls)Specification.pdf)

Specifies the Excel Binary File Format (.xls) Structure, which is the binary file format used by Microsoft Excel 97, Microsoft Excel 2000, Microsoft Excel 2002, and Microsoft Office Excel 2003. This format is also supported by Microsoft Office Excel 2007.

[Office File Formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc313118%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

[Office File Formats PDF .zip file](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=119249)